# What is the ideal way to make collection reference in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongoid

I am new to mongodb, I have only one collection called "stores", here "company" has many "stores", should I make company as separate table and make reference to "stores" table or below is ok?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"),
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {
        "name" : "aa",
        "address" : "bb",
        "company" : "AAA"
    },
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            yyyy,
            xxxx
        ]
    }
}
```

What is the ideal way to call company reference in mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB, you can embed related data in a single structure or document or you can store in a normalized way. It is based on the requirement.

Below are from MongoDB documentation

In general, use embedded data models when:

> 1. you have “contains” relationships between entities. See Model One-to-One Relationships with Embedded Documents.
> 2. you have one-to-many relationships between entities. In these relationships the “many” or child documents always appear with or are
>      viewed in the context of the “one” or parent documents. See Model
>      One-to-Many Relationships with Embedded Documents.

In general, use normalized data models:

> 1. when embedding would result in duplication of data but would not provide sufficient read performance advantages to outweigh the
>      implications of the duplication.
> 2. to represent more complex many-to-many relationships.
> 3. to model large hierarchical data sets.

More details can be found for [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/#data-modeling-embedding) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/#normalized-data-models)

And this [SOF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318161/mongodb-database-structure-and-best-practices-help) might help you as well.

In your case, if the relationship between stores and company is one-to-many then use the embedded structure.